# How to login user and Admin in same page

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to Login with username and password in this way.Based on input values the pages should redirect.But i am not able to login.

```
    <%@include file="database.jsp" %>
    <%

        String User = request.getParameter("User");
        String Pass = request.getParameter("Pass");

        if (User.equals("admin") && Pass.equals("admin123")) {
            response.sendRedirect("AdminHome.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("Adminerror.jsp");
        }

        if (User != "admin") {
            String sql = "select * from user where username='" + User + "' and password='" + Pass + "'";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            if (rs.next()) {

                response.sendRedirect("userhome.jsp");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("usererror.jsp");
            }
        }

    %>
```

Comment: Excuse me...but you have not finished the story,you was saying something about  '**trying to Login with username and password**' then what happened next?...Please post the error you are getting

Comment: if (User != "cadmin") "cadmin" should be "admin"

Comment: based upon the username and password the pages should redirect . if username is admin and password is admin123 it should redirect to admin page else it should redirect to error page. same way with user too

Comment: @JoaoPalma I tried with that also but its not redirecting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using scriplet when you should use servlets. Servlets are simpler to write, test and debug than scriplets.

In you code, you will never properly reach the *user* part. Either you give correct admin user and pass and you should be redirected to `AdminHome.jsp`, else you pass through the `response.sendRedirect("Adminerror.jsp");`

If user was `admin` you should be properly redirected to `AdminHome.jsp` (provided there is nothing else after what you show). But else you will call twice `sendRedirect` which should cause an error.

You should at least test separately user and password for the admin part to avoid the `response.sendRedirect("Adminerror.jsp");` branch if user is not admin and the multiple redirection error.

You should also try to type directly in your browser the URL with `AdminHome.jsp` to be sure that it is correctly accessible from the browser.

Comment: so two redirects not making any sense .?

Comment: @user2503585 : from the `HttpServletResponse` javadoc concerning the `sendRedirect` method : *If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to*. So effectively 2 redirects is an error.